# Как сделать всплывающую подсказку скроляющейся

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На данном [сайте](https://nadv.ru/work/info/) реализована интерактивная возможность по клику на блоки с надписями "территории опережающего развития" и т.д, создавать всплывающие блоки над элементами svg.

Блоки создаются и меняются по клику, но не скролятся вместе с картой.

Как можно решить проблемы скрола? Они должны следовать за картой.

JS который создает блоки:

```
(function($) {
  $('.capabilities-wrapp .capabilities-caption').click(function() {
      $('.tooltip').remove();
      $('.stat-capabilites_map path.cls-3').each(function(e) {
       $('body').prepend('<div class="sss" id="sss'+e+'"></div>');
          $("#sss"+e).html($(this).attr('title')).css({"top":$(this).offset().top, "left":$(this).offset().left});
      })

  });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS всплывающего блока:

```
.sss { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Можете выложить структуру HTML ?

Comment: Даниил, добавил проект на гитхаб 

https://github.com/Clasen00/nadv_test

запускайте index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел сайт, да, создаются по клику эти тултипы, но при скролле - удаляются сразу. http://joxi.ru/LmGVM0dIeO0a8r Приведенной выше функции мало, ищи в скриптах функцию их удаления на скролл.

А если в общем - удаление сделано не с проста, и извиняюсь за прямоту, потому, что само решение привязать тултипы к body а не самой карте - бестолковое, и даже если при скролле их удаление будет отменено, то при ресайзе окна они будут оказываться х.з. где сбоку.
Да и карта фиксируется при скролле.

В общем функцию позиционирования тултипов над картой нужно переписать, сделать привязку к карте, а не body.